# not able to get float value from python script in C# windows app

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have a python script which reads datatable passed from C#. But when i try to get the value of variable in python script.. it does not fetch value. This issue occurs only for varible of type float.
Example  when i try to fetch value of "ErrorRate" ( in python script), it returns 0.0 value only.. though the actaule value is 37.55

// C# script

```
// dt is datatable from C# being passed to python
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
               ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

               ScriptRuntime runTime = Python.CreateRuntime();
               ScriptEngine pyEngine = runTime.GetEngine("py");
               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

               scope.SetVariable("dt",dtmp);

               runTime.IO.SetOutput(ms, new StreamWriter(ms));
               ScriptSource ss = pyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
                                     txtPythonCode.Text.Trim(),
                                      SourceCodeKind.Statements);

               ss.Execute(scope);
               dynamic v1 = scope.GetVariable("Error");
               dynamic v3 = scope.GetVariable<float>("ErrorRate");
               string str = ReadFromStream(ms);

// Python script

    import clr
    clr.AddReference('System.Data')
    from System import Data
    from System.Data import DataTable

    TW = "Button1"
    TotalCnt =0;
    ErrorRate = 0.0;
    Error =0;


    # Function definition is here
    def GetErrorRate(erate,total):
       ErrorRate = float( erate / TotalCnt )*100
       print("Error rate - ",float( erate / TotalCnt )*100);
       return;

    for row in dt.Rows:
        if TW == row[3]:
           print("TotalCnt  - ",TotalCnt)     
        elif row[3]=="X":
           TotalCnt = TotalCnt +1
        elif row[3]=="Y":
           TotalCnt = TotalCnt +1
        elif row[3]=="Z":
           TotalCnt = TotalCnt +1
        elif row[3]==" Wire":
           print()
        else:
          TotalCnt = TotalCnt +1
          Error = Error +1

    GetErrorRate(Error,TotalCnt)
```

Really don't know what could be the reason for the issue.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x then `float( erate / TotalCnt )` may not be doing what you want it to. If `erate` and `TotalCnt` are both integers, then `erate / TotalCnt` will be calculated using **integer** division, so you have to convert (at least) one of them to float **before** performing the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) observed, you are probably doing integer division. This means any decimal part of number gets discarded. Now the result as you told us should be `37.55`. To get that you are multiplying by `100`, so the result of `erate / TotalCnt` should be `0.3755`. If this would be an integer division, the result of that would be, however, `0`. You then convert this `0` into `0.0` with `float` constructor, multiply by `100` and there you get the result, `0.0`.

Solution for this is very simple, just use `TotalCnt = 0.0` instead of `TotalCnt =0;`. That will make the `TotalCnt` variable `float` from start and you will perform floating point operations each time using it.

**PS:** You don't need to use semicolons `;` after statements in python

Comment: thanks.. it's working now.. did the changes as suggested

Comment: 1 more doubt.. how do i to return value TotalCnt from script

Comment: I assume by returning you want to have it in your C# program. You can use the same mechanism as used for retrieving `ErrorRate`, therefore adding this line `dynamic totalCnt = scope.GetVariable<float>("TotalCnt");` to your C# file right after `dynamic v1 = scope.GetVariable("Error");` should do the trick.